# How to use the standard error message

Tags: lemoon

I can't seem to find out how to use the standard "slide in from top" error in Lemoon CMS. Anyone tackled this problem before? I'm trying to use the error for my own login module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call SetMessage(string message, string type, int duration) from your code behind. The SetMessage method is defined in the Lemoon.Web.UI.Admin.PageBase class. That means it will probably not work on the public part of your site, only from the admin section.

Comment: Thats a pity. Would have been a nice addition. Checked it, and it is indeed not possible. So have to create a custom one.